# Remove a component from history in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-components, angular-component-router

How could i restrict a component to load on back press.
Actually i have three component A(Normal Component), B(LoginComponent) and C(Otp Verification Component).
I'm routing to component B from A on some button click and from B to C to verify user.
now after verification done on component C, i want to go back on component 'A', and want to remove component 'B' and 'C' from history so that on back press from browser it does not load 'B'(LoginComponent) and 'C' again.
so how could i do this in angularjs 2.

Comment: I suppose you could use route guards. [RouteGuards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

Comment: They allow you to hook into the component lifecycle giving you the ability to cancel navigation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While navigating from components B and C, pass the option `replaceUrl:true` to replace B with C in the browser history.

Eg:

```
//Navigating to state C 
this.router.navigate(["/C"], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Checkout the [documentation for replaceUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl)